# NSControl isEnabled only available in OS X v10.0 through OS X v10.9

Tags: cocoa, appkit, nscontrol

Does anybody know why NSControl's isEnabled has been removed while setEnabled: is still working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In OS X 10.10 (and iOS 8), many of the getter/setter method pairs in Apple's frameworks were replaced by `@property` declarations. This both makes the header interface clearer and makes the import of those APIs into Swift more... well, Swifty.

```
// Before
- (BOOL)isEnabled;
- (void)setEnabled:(BOOL)enabled;

// After
@property(getter=isEnabled) BOOL enabled
```

The documentation hasn't been fully updated to reflect that, so it erroneously shows `isEnabled` as deprecated, even though the `@property` declaration means you can still do any of the following:

```
BOOL foo = [control isEnabled];
[control setEnabled:YES];
BOOL bar = control.enabled;
control.enabled = YES;
```

Comment: Thanks! This also applies to the `continuous` method / property. However many of the other declarations that are crossed out in the `NSControl` docs *are* actually deprecated: I've tried to decode this a bit in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32102638/2047122).