# In OS X 10.10, can I implement an NSControl without an NSCell?

Tags: macos, cocoa, osx-yosemite, nscell, nscontrol

I am learning about `NSControl`. I am aware that `NSCell` has begun its road to deprecation in OS X 10.10 Yosemite, and so I'd rather not use an API that is going away. Also, the `NSControl` Class Reference shows all cell accessors have been deprecated.

I understand all this, but what is not as clear is what the recommended course is for people writing `NSControl` subclasses on 10.10. All of the Apple guides on the subject make no mention of the deprecation of `NSCell`. I suppose I could just do things the old way, but then I'd need to change my code when Apple advances the deprecation of `NSCell` to the next level.

Is it even possible to implement an `NSControl` subclass without using `NSCell` at all?

Can anyone provide advice or link me to a resource on this subject? This is proving difficult to google.

Comment: I can't see the way to subclass `NSControl` without using `NSCell`. Simple because `NSControl` still relies on `NSCell` (even if it is deprecated). If you need to build a unique custom user interface control (say, volume control), then maybe better to subclass `NSView`. But, if you need to customise standard `NSControl`, then adjusting `NSCell` properties or even "lightweight subclassing" of the `NSCell` should not be a problem.

Answer (score 5):

I'm trying to work this out as well.  I can't unfortunately answer all your questions, but here's what I've found so far.

The [AppKit Release Notes for OS X v10.10](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/AppKit/RN-AppKit/) have a brief explanation of what is happening, which I originally saw in the question [How to create a custom themed NSButton without subclassing NSButtonCell?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28700605/2047122).

> ## Gradual deprecation of NSCell
>
> Mac OS X 10.10 takes another step towards the eventual deprecation of
>   cells. Direct access to the cell of a control is discouraged, and
>   methods which allow it will be formally deprecated in a subsequent
>   release. A variety of cell-level APIs have been promoted to various
>   Control subclasses in order to provide cell-free access to important
>   functionality. NSLevelIndicator, NSTextField, NSSearchField, NSSlider,
>   and NSPathControl all have new properties for this purpose. Cell-based
>   NSTableViews are now deprecated, and view-based NSTableViews should be
>   used instead. Matrix-based NSBrowsers are also deprecated in favor of
>   the item-based interface.

The 10.10 documentation does have many NSControl methods crossed out in red.  (By the way, I'm not sure if this unambiguously means "deprecated".)

The documentation markings for `continuous` and `enabled` are misleading, however.  I've looked through the header file for `NSControl` at the declarations that are crossed out in the docs and there seem to be a few different things going on:

1. This method is deprecated with `NS_DEPRECATED_MAC`:

   ```
   // Use formatters instead.  See -[NSControl formatter] and -[NSControl setFormatter:].
   - (void)setFloatingPointFormat:(BOOL)autoRange left:(NSUInteger)leftDigits right:(NSUInteger)rightDigits NS_DEPRECATED_MAC(10_0, 10_0);
   ```
2. These methods appear in an `NSDeprecated` category:

   ```
   @interface NSControl (NSDeprecated)

   // Use formatters instead.  See -[NSControl formatter] and -[NSControl setFormatter:].
   - (void)setFloatingPointFormat:(BOOL)autoRange left:(NSUInteger)leftDigits right:(NSUInteger)rightDigits NS_DEPRECATED_MAC(10_0, 10_0);

   + (void)setCellClass:(Class)factoryId;
   + (Class)cellClass;

   - (id)cell;
   - (void)setCell:(NSCell *)aCell;
   - (id)selectedCell;
   - (NSInteger)selectedTag;

   - (void)setNeedsDisplay;    // Use setNeedsDisplay:YES instead.
   - (void)calcSize;

   - (void)updateCell:(NSCell *)aCell;
   - (void)updateCellInside:(NSCell *)aCell;
   - (void)drawCellInside:(NSCell *)aCell;
   - (void)drawCell:(NSCell *)aCell;
   - (void)selectCell:(NSCell *)aCell;

   @end
   ```
3. These methods appear in the documentation as "Available in OS X v10.8 through OS X v10.9", but not in the NSControl header file, so I assume they've been removed completely:

   ```
   -userInterfaceLayoutDirection
   -setUserInterfaceLayoutDirection
   ```
4. These declarations were previously methods, but have been refactored into properties.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28707348/2047122) for details about what happened to the isEnabled / setEnabled methods.  So these declarations are crossed out in the docs, but this is misleading:

   ```
   @property (getter=isContinuous) BOOL continuous;
   @property (getter=isEnabled) BOOL enabled;
   ```

I haven't found any good information about how to create an `NSControl` subclass without also creating an `NSCell` subclass, although apparently `NSColorWell` is a cell-less `NSControl`.

My current rough conclusion is that `NSControl` is coupled fairly strongly to `NSCell`, and it isn't sensible to use one without the other.  So I'm considering writing an `NSView` subclass instead.

I'd also appreciate more information and advice here!